# Hive Beeline parameters in Shell Script

Tags: shell, unix, hive, hiveql, beeline

​Hello everybody,

I want to use beeline in Shell script and it not working properly . can someone help me to resolve this .

**main_script.sh**

```
source /file_path/configs.sh -- with 777 permission 

beeline -u ${hive_connection_string} -n $USER_NAME -p $PASSWORD -f /usr/hql/query.hql
```

**configs.sh**

```
current_dir="/data/landing/"

hive_connection_string='jdbc:hive2://host1:2181,host2:2181,host3:2181/;serviceDiscoveryMode=zooKeeper;zooKeeperNamespace=hiveserver2;#currentdir='${current_dir}
```

**query.hql**

```
create external table ( ....) location /user/hdfs_path/landingdir/ --> this directory is also not picking in the main script .
```

What is the main thing am I missing or how can I achieve this .

When we try to run the ./main_script.sh the values -n $USER_NAME/password is not picking in the main script . What am I doing wrong . I think it is taking me to beeline session instead of Unix shell values.

Have tried this step alone for many hours , tried all the possibilites of single quotes , double quotes , flower braces without braces. It didn't seem to work . what is right way to approach this

Comment: Can you clarify "not picking"? Specifically, what do you expect to happen that is not happening?

Comment: Greg's Wiki has an excellent explanation of [quoting](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes).

Comment: @l0b0 I have declared all the variables in bash shell, when beeline begins , it creates its own session . the variable which I have declared in bash is not being used by the beeline session . I'm getting lot of errors of variable not being used . If I use the variables in the main.sh file itself beeline is able to use the variables from bash .

Comment: You should be aware that the `#` sign in a shell command means **ignore the rest of the line, it's just a comment**. Safer to use command-line arguments `--hiveconf ` and `--hivevar` than trying to tinker with the URL args equivalents _(these are only useful for Java programs)_

Comment: And from general principles, use double quotes when invoking shell variables, especially when they are susceptible to contain blanks/semicolons/hash/star/question mark etc -- i.e. `beeline -u "$hive_connection_string" -n "$USER_NAME" -p "$PASSWORD"`

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter We need to invoke the location value from the Shell script  create external table ( ....) location "$current_dir" . This is not working as expected whereas current_dir="/data/landing/" and this is stored in hql file . I cannot use shell script values in hql session